# SSL Timeout issue with Ubuntu running LAMP and Certbot on Free AWS Tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, lamp, certbot

Port 443 looks to be open:

```
$ netstat -ptnl | grep ":443"
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

Firewall 443 rules added. Turning off Firewall made no difference.

80 works fine. Certbot generated with no issues. The generated conf is active.

No errors, despite adding error logs in default apache2 conf and sites ssl vhost.conf
Syntax checked, SSL valid.

Any suggestions to test further?

Comment: It looks like you only have IPv6 enabled for HTTPS.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but I have not found a command to enable for v4. @JohnHanley what would that be?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that AWS has "Security Rules" that required enabling on the site dashboard.